# Facebook app develop - get only friends with birthday

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I was searching for this topic but with no luck.
I currently got all the friends from user (name,id,birthday).
Is there any way to prevent from checking all the friend birthday list and just get from 
the user a list of friends that have birthday? (**from the Facebook birthday app reminder** )
thanks

Comment: The code here should give you the results you want:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5580128/sorting-by-birthday-date-my-friend-list-in-facebook-api/5664020#5664020